# Bootstrap Modals are empty on first call

Tags: jquery, node.js, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a NodeJs App with some Bootstrap modals in the same view. The HTML(ejs) looks like:

```
<!--Main link-->
<a id = "myLink" data-toggle="modal" href="/path/to/myModal.ejs" data-nom="<%=user.name%>" data-id="<%=user._id%>" data-curs="<%=user.level%>" data-body = "<%=user.body%>" data-target="#ModalUpd">Update body</a>

<!-- Call the remote Modal-->    
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalUpd" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This link calls this remote Modal:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Update user</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          Update user
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <strong>User: </strong><span id="userNom"></span>
                <strong>Curs: </strong><span id="userCurs"></span>
<!--BODY UPDATE-->
              <form role="form" method="post" id="upd">
                  <label for="BodyUpd">Body</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="BodyUpd" form="upd"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>    
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" form="upd" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="updBtn">Update</button>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

and there is a jQuery file containing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){    
$("#myLink").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var userN = $(this).data('nom');
      var userC = $(this).data('curs');
      var userId = $(this).data('id');
      var userbody = $(this).data('body');

        $("#userN").text(userN);
        $("#userC").text(userC);
        $("#BodyUpd").attr("name", "user.body");
        $("#BodyUpd").val(body);

        $('#updBtn').on('submit', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var urlPost = "/path/" + userId + "/otherpath/" + "?_method=put";
          $('#modalUpd').modal('toggle');
          $.ajax({
              url: urlPost
              type: 'POST',
              data: $('#upd').serialize()
          });
          location.reload();
        });
      });
    });
```

It works perfect, but never on first call. The first time I call the modal, all the fields are empty, with no user data. When I close the modal and re-call, then appears all the user data in the modal.
I'm pretty new in jQuery and I think I'm doing something wrong with "$(document).ready" but I don't know what... I've tried a lot of different possibilities, but this is the best I found.
Hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: you are calling document.ready within document.on click? do it the other way

Comment: Why do you have a doc ready function inside of an onclick? That is the source of your issue. doc ready should run once, on complete page load. It should never be inside another function.

Comment: I've tried to put document.ready before onclick (as I've edited the code on question) but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution and it was pretty simple: I had about 30 document.ready in the JS file. One for each function. Now I've enclosed all functions in one document.ready. Perhaps it's not too cute, but it works.